# Url redirection error in AngularJs

Tags: html, angularjs

```
<a href="www.google.com" target="_blank">google</a>
```

when i clicked on this tag than i redirected to

```
 http://localhost:55943/www.google.com
```

I tried below code also,

```
$window.location.href = "www.google.com";
```

but both case I redirected to

```
 http://localhost:55943/www.google.com page.
```

Comment: use : <a href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank">google</a>

Comment: it is not AngularJS question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A href without a protocol definition will always be treated as a relative URL. You need to type `http://www.google.com` in order for it to be understood as an absolute URL.

Update your HTML to:

`<a href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank">google</a>`

Also take a look at the [W3 explanation](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_href.asp) of the HREF attribute.

Answer (score 0):

As GordyD says, if you don't define any protocol it will be treated as a relative URL.
You need to prefix external URLs with **http://**, **https://** or **//**

**//** will open the external url using the same protocol as your current application is running